# How to manipulate a JPEG with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, jpeg, image-manipulation

I'm having a problem with image manipulation in classic ASP.
I need o know the size of the image, so I can make a if statement.

How can I do this with classic asp?
Do I need to use javascript/Jquery instead?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GetDimensions. Example:

```
Set Image = Server.CreateObject("csImageFile.Manage")
Image.GetDimensions "C:\images\test.jpg"
Response.Write Image.ReadWidth & "<br/>"
Response.Write Image.ReadHeight & "<br/>"
```